How to run failed testcases using pabot with multiple argument files (different set of data)
Goal: I am using pabot (https://pabot.org/) to run some test cases with different users in parallel, however when I try to use the '--rerunfailed' argument with multiple users, it fails as demonstrated below and I would like to use '--rerunfailed' with parallel tasks and with multiple argument files (different set of users). I am able to get it to work without mulitple users though.
Environment: I have created a sample environment to help illustrate the issue:
testsuite\common.robot
*** Settings ***
Test Tags   smoke

*** Test Cases ***

Test1
    [Documentation]  This is a test case 1 for ${USER}
    Sleep            1s
    Log              This is a test case 1

Test2
    [Documentation]  This is a test case 2 for ${USER}
    Sleep            2s
    Log              This is a test case 2

Test3
    [Documentation]  This is a test case 3 for ${USER}
    Sleep            3s
    Log              This is a test case 3

Test4
    [Documentation]  This is a test case 4 for ${USER}
    Sleep            4s
    Log              This is a test case 4

Test5
    [Documentation]  This is a test case 5 for ${USER}
    Sleep            5s
    Fail              This is a test case 5

I have created 3 arguments files to run with 3 different users
userOne.txt
--name=USERONE
--variable USER:userOne

userTwo.txt
--name=USERTWO
--variable USER:userTwo

userThree.txt
--name=USERTHREE
--variable USER:userThree


If we run the test the first time, it runs in parallel, and output XML is generated as expected merging all 3 (users) results. Below is the 1st command used to run all testcases with all users in parallel (am running suite in parallel with all users simultaneously)

pabot --processes 3 \
--argumentfile1 results\userOne.txt \
--argumentfile2 results\userTwo.txt \
--argumentfile3 results\userThree.txt \
-i smoke --name SmokeFunctions --output parallel.xml -d results testsuite\common.robot


If any testcase is failed, am running same command but using --rerunfailed switch.

Command
pabot --processes 3 \
--argumentfile1 results\userOne.txt \
--argumentfile2 results\userTwo.txt \
--argumentfile3 results\userThree.txt \
--rerunfailed results\parallel.xml --output parallel_rerun.xml \
--name SmokeFunctions -d results testsuite\common.robot

Error shown is :
Suite 'SmokeFunctions' contains no tests matching name 'SmokeFunctions.userOne.common.Test5', 'SmokeFunctions.userTwo.common.Test5' or 'SmokeFunctions.userThree.common.Test5'.

Environment:

Windows 11/Chrome
Python 3.12.4
Pip 24.1.2
robotframework 7.0.1
robotframework-pabot 2.18.0

Any help/suggestion is appreciated on this.
Thanks
